# How to do partitions when they involve equations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, advice

$B_r $={(x,y):$x^2 +y^2=$r}for each r $\in $ R

$ B_r$ is an index family of classes
(Ref pg 40 A book of set theory.Pinter .electronic version 
45 of224.or on google version 40 of 224

P1.∀r,s∈R, $B_r∩B_s=Ø$ Or $B_r=B_s$

1. I have to show each circle is disjoint for each $r$ $\in$ R
2. it’s union is B.

( This is either to obvious or involves 
more work .I am new to this subject. 
Working with sets and modulo ok)

Proof by contradiction

Assume they aren’t disjoint then (a,b) $\in $$ B_r $ $\cap $ $B_s$-> $a^2+b^2=r^2$
and  $a^2+b^2=s^2$  Then$r^2=s^2$

These concentric circles at (0,0) share origin then r=s

So r=s & r!=s. Contradiction. So P1 is satisfied .

Since they are disjoint it’s union is B

Answer (score 0):

Assume (a,b) in $B_r \cap B_r$.
Then r = $a^2 + b^2$ = s.
Take it from there.

Notice that B$_r$ is not a partition.  Why?
What is B?

Comment: B_r is a family of equivalence classes of modula B

Comment: What I see is "(a,b) in □□$\cap$□".  Use a different character set.@HomerSimpson

Comment: B_r is a set!  modula B is meaningless.

Comment: See page 40 and 41 of A Book of set theory by Pinter’ https://books.google.com/books/about/A_Book_of_Set_Theory.html?hl=es&id=q1KVAwAAQBAJ

Comment: Got the module idea from page 77 of 224 of electronic version @WilliamElliot I did find it somewhat strange. Modulo math as far I know deals with remainder of one number divided by another, so the symbol looked the somewhat the same ...